# Javascript Onclick event change url link

Tags: javascript

on click event, within Javascript, I need to change url of a link from

http://www.iremsd.org/events/detail.phx?id=78874a5d-3e82-464b-8c78-c259b2e62308spamp;navid=fd201fdd-7e7f-4121-afe5-65004486a2c3

to

http://www.iremsd.org/events/detail.phx?id=78874a5d-3e82-464b-8c78-c259b2e62308&navid=fd201fdd-7e7f-4121-afe5-65004486a2c3

Comment: On a link tag? or... what? Give more details please.

Comment: the question can't be answered without making significant assumptions, you should add more information

Comment: Are you telling about format or an instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of JS that will change a link from one url to another on the click of a button.

```js
function change(){
  
  var linkElement = document.getElementById("link");
  linkElement.href = "http://bing.com";
   
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" id="link">This goes somewhere...</a>
<button onClick="change()">Change link</button>
```

Comment: Thanks.However my issue is that & changes to spamp; when I post it to the website.

Comment: I need to change it back to & from spamp; on the click event in javascript